# Is this a right way to get data that is joined via many different tables in Datastore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

ok, let see this table structure in Datastore:

```
Structure Table
StructureNo StructureName
1           Structure1
2           Structure2


Line Table
LineNo LineName StructureNo
1      Line1    1
2      Line2    1
3      Line3    2
```

Let say we want to show all the Lines with their structures as the following:

```
LineNo LineName StructureNo StructureName
1      Line1    1           Structurre1
2      Line2    1           Structurre1
3      Line3    2           Structurre2
```

Google said that we can't do the Join, then what is the professional way to get data?

So, we first

```
filter all lines in Line Table
//put StructureNo into a structureNoList<Integer>
//then filter all structures in Structure Table that have structureNo in the  structureNoList<Integer>
//then assemble line and structure data via Java list
```

**Is this a right way to get data that is joined via many different tables in Datastore?**

Comment: yes, that's one of right ways

Comment: @IgorArtamonov, no other way right?

Comment: for this concrete example, that will be optimal way. but for real database there could be better solutions

Comment: You also need to think about all the queries you need to do on these kinds - for example, the number of indexed values for a single property is [capped at 1000](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/indexselection).